# Como incentivar quem vai responder a fazer uma pesquisa prévia no site?

Tags: debate, comportamento, perguntas-duplicadas

Creio que é dever de todos verificarmos se já não existem boas respostas e marcamos como duplicata para ajudar o site, como podemos orientar o novos usuários, principalmente os que estão respondendo perguntas (já que provavelmente eles são mais participativos no site do que quem pergunta, claro que a orientação deve servir para todo)?

Comment: Guilherme tens toda a razão, e peço desculpa, sei que não devo fazer mas de facto não me lembro sempre de ver se são duplicadas e quando vejo que são também não respondo (sem te querer tirar a razão), desde a data da tua ultima chamada de atenção (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179592/como-fazer-download-de-arquivo-sem-back-end/179595?noredirect=1#comment371413_179595) que não (acho) respondi a nenhuma que eu tenha visto que era.

Comment: Independentemente disso noto muitas vezes que o titulo da pergunta nada tem a haver com as originais (apesar da sua solução ser a mesma), o que torna a pesquisa por duplicadas mais dificil. 80% das vezes as pessoas que votam como duplicada são autores das perguntas/respostas originais, dai lembrarem-se melhor se já existe ou não solução/explicação para aquela duvida. Não me estou a tentar desculpar a 100% (porque realmente devo ver se existem)

Comment: Bom exemplo Guilherme, como vez: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=document.getElementById%20vs%20Id , a duplicada aí fui eu que a fiz, nenhuma das outras parece ter a ver/resolver a minha duvida (eu próprio tive dificuldade em arranjar um titulo claro/conciso para a pergunta), nesse caso como encontraria http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123098/porque-usar-getelementbyid-se-o-id-esta-no-window (original)

Comment: Eu sei Guilherme, e agradeço. Agora vou ler as respostas em baixo, para ver se interiorizo isso de vez. De qualquer maneira peço desculpa porque eu sei que não se deve fazer, é apenas distração / falta de hábito / não saber fazer com eficácia

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, peço desculpas mais uma vez por qualquer inconveniente e faço minhas as palavras dos dois primeiros comentários do Miguel. Desde a última vez que você me avisou das duplicidades, tenho marcado perguntas como duplicadas (uma até você informou que não via como duplicada... e concordei com você no caso). Durante este tempo, tenho percebido que muitos outros usuários continuam respondendo a questões duplicadas, inclusive usuários com alta pontuação.

Comment: Uma vez fiz uma pergunta sobre isso aqui no meta e a resposta foi um pouco diferente.. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4707/6036
Nesta resposta a visão da duplicação não é tão negativa, nem mesmo a de respostas duplicadas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não estou chateado não. Sei que não sou só eu e o Miguel que fizeram isso e certamente não tem só mais uns 3... então... uma vez que muita gente faz isso, até mesmo usuários experientes, como eu e o Miguel, o que fazer para mitigar este problema?

Comment: Favorecer respostas antigas nem sempre é bom, elas podem estar desatualizadas... Pode ter surgido uma forma melhor de fazer. Esse artigo é bem legal sobre duplicações: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha entendido. O que eu entendi que você está sugerindo é que se pesquise a fundo no site se existe uma resposta para a pergunta que você vai responder. Eu não concordo com essa sugestão e estou argumentando... Perguntas e respostas duplicadas são boas se acontecerem na proporção correta (é exatamente o que diz no lik que mandei acima). Responder a perguntas duplicadas ajuda bastante na criação de novas respostas, é um incentivo para surgirem novas respostas para pergunats que já tem respostas (problema relatado aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5705/6036)

Answer (score 5):

Dei uma pesquisada nos outros Metas e vou colocar algumas opiniões sobre esse assunto...

1. [Is it my responsibility to search for duplicates & vote to close before answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91180/294211)

A resposta aceita é:

> Unless you recall a specific question that you think is a duplicate,
>   it's not an expectation that you do exhaustive searching to look for a
>   duplicate.
>
> One handy thing to check is the "Related" questions in the sidebar on
>   the right. If some of the title seem eerily similar, check some of
>   those out first and see if they may be exact (emphasis on exact)
>   duplicates and act accordingly.

A [segunda resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105231/294211), com o mesmo número de votos que a resposta aceita é um pouco mais incisiva no dever de pesquisar. Mas nem tanto...

2. [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/294211)

Pergunta e resposta tem bastante votos, e a proposição é dar pontos para quem encontra duplicadas, assim incentivando a ação.

Aqui tem mais uma pergunta:

3. [Should users answer blatant exact duplicates without noting that it's a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86303/294211)

Aqui a resposta diz que usuários experientes devem saber se é duplicado. Achei interessante os comentários de um moderador.

> How are you certain that the one who provided the answer knew it was a
>   duplicate? The answer was posted before the comment indicating a
>   duplicate. I also remember merging the 'answer' the OP made with the
>   question, I don't recall seeing any close votes (which would have
>   prompted me to consider closing or merging the whole question once
>   done)

Em outro comenário ele fala:

> I also don't scan the 'related' list to the right unless I've found a
>   question through searching that doesn't have answers that help me, or
>   if I'm looking to see if something might have been asked before.
>   Almost never prior to answering questions, but I do tend to spend a
>   little time looking for duplicates of very basic ones prior to
>   answering (if only to avoid wasting time on a question that will soon
>   be closed)

Ou seja, ele só olha a lista de relacionadas se ele estiver procurando uma resposta para um problema dele. Antes de responder ele diz que quase nunca pesquisa por duplicadas, a não ser que seja uma pergunta muito fácil (para não perder tempo com uma pergunta que será fechada)

---

Enfim, acho que está longe de ser um consenso de que não devemos responder as perguntas antes de pesquisarmos se ela é duplicada. Deveríamos discutir isso aqui no Meta antes de considerar que isso é errado e apontar usuários por alguma má conduta.

Se fosse p/ incentivar:

Minha opinião é de que é difícil controlar isso sem que quem responda perguntas duplicadas não seja desfavorecido de alguma forma. Comentários nos posts não irão resolver. (você fala mal, mas a pessoa acaba ganhando pontos..)

Negativar a resposta na pergunta duplicada pode ser uma solução. Mas e se a pessoa realmente não achou? Será que é realmente o dever dela procurar tão bem assim? E se a resposta for melhor do que as respostas antigas?

Para mim, a única solução boa seria pontuar quem acha perguntas duplicadas. Isso faz bastante sentido, pois na prática, é como se o usuário tivesse respondido a pergunta. Isso é o que foi dito [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112070/294211). Em 2010...

---

Por curiosidade, como não consegui achar muitas respostas em perguntas duplicadas da forma que você mencionou, fiz uma pesquisa usando a API do StackOverflow. Fiz uma tabelinha de quantidades de perguntas respondidas e o motivo de fechamento para as perguntas respondidas. `NA` significa que a pergunta não foi fechada.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
                   closed_reason miguel allan guilherme
                           <chr>  <int> <int>     <int>
1                      duplicate     16    20        29
2                      off-topic      1     5        47
3        primarily opinion-based      2     1         2
4                      too broad      4     3        10
5 unclear what you&#39;re asking      7     2        40
6                           <NA>    421   140       806
```

O Miguel e o Guilherme possuem em proporção ao número de respostas praticamente o mesmo valor de respostas em perguntas duplicadas (3%). O Allan possui um pouco mais (quase 12%)...

Se quiser o código posso passar.

Comment: A minha resposta é: será que é pra incentivar? Veja as opiniões de várias pessoas. Não é um consenso....Você parte do pre-suposto de que é, eu estou um passo atrás.

Comment: o usuário que marcou como duplicado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento precisa, antes de tudo, verificar se é mesmo um problema. Ao meu ver, não é.

Comment: 1. Avalio todas as perguntas para as quais tenho conehcimento. 2. Todas que tenho conehcimento. 3. Sim. 4. Já

Comment: Claro, sei sim.

Comment: Isso deveria influenciar a minha opinião?

Comment: Isso não é o número de fechamentos. É o número de perguntas que você respondeu e que foram fechadas por serem duplicadas.

Comment: Eu avalio percentualmente, comparado ao número de perguntas respondidas. Leia atentamente.

Comment: O Objetivo de se fechar uma pergunta é exatamente não receber respostas. Se você responde... Para que serviria...

Comment: Você acha ideal, mas a comunidade acha? Eu estou dizendo que não acho e faço parte da comunidade (tanto quanto você). Você pode citar outros usuários? Eu gostaria de avaliar.

Comment: Vou esperar outras opiniões aqui. Para mim, essa estratégia está equivocada... Aqui sendo uma comunidade, você não pode usar uma estratégia que não está indicada na ajuda ou discutida no MEta, só porque tem mais pontos... Talvez os moderadores tenham esse direito uma vez que são eleitos.

Comment: Todos os comentários do Guilherme foram removidos. Ficou um negócio meio estranho aqui...