# Responder perguntas duplicadas para evitar que sejam respondidas por usuários inexperientes ou mal-intencionados?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

[Este comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5719/como-incentivar-quem-vai-responder-a-fazer-uma-pesquisa-pr%c3%a9via-no-site?cb=1#comment21799_5738) fala sobre uma estratégia para lidar com perguntas duplicadas:

> Daniel eu já falei uma vez, eu mesmo respondo perguntas que eu fecho,
>   por motivos como evitar respostas ruins de suporte por parte de
>   usuários inexperientes. Geralmente elas tem links para outras
>   respostas. A ideia é evitar respostas ruins (o que acontece muito) ou
>   respostas repetitivas e apontar para respostas mais completas, é uma
>   estratégia que comecei a fazer para evitar que o AP receba respostas
>   genericas ou ruins. Afinal isso não é um site de suporte né :)

Essa estratégia é reconhecida, ou seja, devo aplicá-la quando encontrar essas situações?

Answer (score 7):

Na minha opinião, não.

Não sei em como responder a perguntas duplicadas evita que surjam outras respostas, quer seja boas ou más.
Para evitar que surjam respostas, deve-se votar para fechar.

Se temos condições para dar uma resposta melhor do que as que já existem, devemos dá-la na primeira pergunta.

Talvez o seu entendimento de "pergunta duplicada" seja mais abrangente do que o meu. Eu estou a referir-me a "perguntas duplicadas" no sentido em que:

> (...)A pergunta só é duplicada se ela produzir respostas iguais. Se for possível juntá-las e ninguém notar que algumas respostas de uma pergunta foram dadas no outra.(..)
>   <sub>(bigown em [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/609/2541) à pergunta [Lidando com perguntas duplicadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/607/2541))</sub>

Comment: Não entendo como isso pode forçar um fechamento mais rápido.

Comment: Se surgirem respostas ruins, vote negativo e sinalize para remover. Note que este é o entendimento que eu tenho das "regras de moderação", posso estar errado.

Comment: Não é isso @GuilhermeNascimento. Talvez a sua estratégia seja boa, mas precisa ser debatida pela comunidade. Alguns vão ter opiniões favoráveis e outros contra. Talvez até tenha alguma forma melhor... Deve ser feito aquilo que a comunidade achar melhor... Sabemos que não é moda sua, mas isso não foi debatido pela comunidade...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Isso é verdade, eu já me deparei com situações iguais(algumas até em que tive vontade de responder). No entanto respostas menos boas com muitos upvotes também as há em perguntas "não duplicatas".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sim por isso abri a discussão. Vamos ver o que outros usuários (tão experientes como você) agem nessas situações. Talvez exista uma maneira melhor do que essa que você encontrou. Quando chegarmos em um consenso atualizamos o que está escrito aqui:http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/607/6036

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a discussão, se não gerar uma forma melhor de agir, vai indicar a sua como a sugestão apra todos e isso é bom. Veja como uma pergunta (que talvez tenha sido meio idiota que eu fiz aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5577/6036) gerou respostas de boa qualidade e melhorou o meu entendimento sobre o site. Eu achava que não estava fazendo nada de errado para o site, mas depois dessa resposta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5578/6036 descobri que estava.

Comment: Não sei como perdeu a oportunidade pra este link obrigatório... https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @EMBarbosa eu não entendi

Comment: @DanielFalbel Se a pergunta é duplicada e já existe(m) resposta(s), então criar outra resposta só aumenta o número de respostas...